xata revese link sorting with createdAt field not working
In xata reverse link can't sort results with createdAt date. Followed as official guide (https://xata.io/docs/concepts/data-model#links-and-relationships) but no luck. Giving error,
FetcherError: Internal Error (Request ID: f3b4a5dc-99e9-94a4-87a8-cfa06828ce11)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@xata.io+client@0.29.4_typescript@5.4.5/node_modules/@xata.io/client/dist/index.mjs:2778:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async defaultTrace (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@xata.io+client@0.29.4_typescript@5.4.5/node_modules/@xata.io/client/dist/index.mjs:196:10)
    at async fetch$1 (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@xata.io+client@0.29.4_typescript@5.4.5/node_modules/@xata.io/client/dist/index.mjs:2721:10)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@xata.io+client@0.29.4_typescript@5.4.5/node_modules/@xata.io/client/dist/index.mjs:5833:42)
    at async defaultTrace (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@xata.io+client@0.29.4_typescript@5.4.5/node_modules/@xata.io/client/dist/index.mjs:196:10)
    at async _Query.getIterator (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@xata.io+client@0.29.4_typescript@5.4.5/node_modules/@xata.io/client/dist/index.mjs:5244:16)
    at async _Query.getAll (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@xata.io+client@0.29.4_typescript@5.4.5/node_modules/@xata.io/client/dist/index.mjs:5272:22)
    at async $$ACTION_0 (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./actions/student.ts:23:25)
    at async D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:418
    at async rS (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:7978)
    at async r2 (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:41:1251)
    at async doRender (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1438:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1599:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1507:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1924:24)        
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1962:32)       
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:920:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:272:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:816:17)
    at async D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:339:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:336:24)       
    at async invokeRender (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:174:21)
    at async handleRequest (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:353:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (D:\projects\eclz\node_modules\.pnpm\next@14.2.3_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18.3.1\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:141:13) {
  status: 500,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Internal Error (Request ID: f3b4a5dc-99e9-94a4-87a8-cfa06828ce11)',
      status: 500
    }
  ],
  requestId: 'f3b4a5dc-99e9-94a4-87a8-cfa06828ce11',
  cause: undefined
}

Tried code snipet,
await xata.db.students
      .select([
        "firstName",
        "grade",
        {
          name: "<-marks.studentId",
          as: "monthsTop",
          columns: ["month", "score"],
          limit: 1,
          offset: 0,
          sort: [
            {
              "xata.createdAt": "desc",
            },
          ],
        },
      ])
      .getAll();

tried also simply,
sort: [
        {
          createdAt: "desc",
        },
       ],

and not working.
But working fine with other column values. such as,
 sort: [
        {
          month: "desc",
        },
       ],

